# How can I nicely handle an ENOENT?

Tags: node.js, express

I've recently started making an Express project.
I made it so if someone goes to `localhost:3000/games/tictactoe`, they receive `/games/tictactoe/index.html`.
(Edit: I want the routes to be dynamic; if a user goes to `/games/foo`, it should send them the `index.html` of that directory.)
My directory structure is:

```
multiplayergames
├── games
│   └── tictactoe
│       └── index.html
└── src
    └── server.js
```

`server.js` (so far)

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
app.get("/games/:game", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(`${req.params.game}/index.html`, {root: "games/"})
})
  
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`App is up! (${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()})`)
})
```

The only problem is, if someone goes to, say, `/games/foo`, it says `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'multiplayergames/games/foo/index.html'`.
Is there any way to send the user a "nicer" response (an HTML page) when they go to a nonexistent game?

[also, if there's something wrong with how I dynamically serve the files, let me know; I threw it together pretty quickly]

Comment: since `localhost:3000/games/tictactoe` is fixed, why dont use write a route for this path instead of path param `/games/:game`. Also, you can use 404 error route to send  custom errors when user tries to visit non existing routes

Comment: @JatinMehrotra, I don't think it's actually a 404 caused by the user going to a nonexistent route; it's because (for example) `/games/foo/index.html` doesn't exist, so Express sends the server error to the user. Instead of sending the error, I wanted it to send an HTML file.

Comment: For your other statement, however, I should have mentioned that I don't want to hard-code the routes like you seem to be suggesting. I added that to the question. Thank you for trying to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use node fs to check if file exist, and return the game, or a custom html file. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsexistssyncpath

```
const fs = require('fs')
app.get("/games/:game", (req, res) => {
     if (fs.existsSync('/path/to/game/index.html')) {
       res.sendFile(`${req.params.game}/index.html`, {root: "games/"})
     } else {
       res.sendFile('custom 404 html file');
     }
})
```